# Move semantics construction failure when variable and parameter names match

Tags: c++, constructor, move

The following is the full code in question; comments show the outputs.

Apparently, variable is set in `Class1` even if initially missing. `Class2` shows how changing the formal parameter's name to one that differs from the member variable helps.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Class1
  { 
public:
    string name;
    Class1(string name):name(move(name)) { cout << name << endl; } // NULL ???
   ~Class1() { cout << name << endl; }  // foo
  };


class Class2
  { 
public:
    string name;
    Class2(string s):name(move(s)) { cout << name << endl; } // bar
   ~Class2() { cout << name << endl; }  // bar
  };


int main(void)
  { Class1 x("foo");
    Class2 y("bar");
  }
```

Comment: What's the question or the problem? Try `Class1(string name):name(move(name)) { cout << this->name << endl; }`

Comment: Your parameter and your member variable are named the same. In the constructor of `Class1` you're printing a local variable that has been moved not the member.

Comment: You are also missing the standard library includes `#include<string>` for `string` and `#include<utility>` for `move`. If it happens to work without them, that is pure coincidence.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter shadows the member variable. That's expected behavior. You can fix it with:

```
Class1(string name):name(move(name)) {
    cout << "argument: " << name << endl; // NULL
    cout << "member: " << this->name << endl; // foo
}
```

It's unrelated to move. Try:

```
Class1(string name):name("member"+name)) {
    cout << "argument: " << name << endl; // foo
    cout << "member: " << this->name << endl; // memberfoo
}
```

Comment: Technical nit.  An _argument_ is what the caller passes in, and _parameter_ is the variable named in the parameter list.  `cout << "parameter: " << name << endl;`

Comment: @Eljay Accuracy is important in programming. Unfortunately, I often mix them up.

Comment: You, me, and many others too.  This particular nit finally got pounded into my brain.  13 years of college, and that's the one thing that stuck.

Answer (score 0):

In `Class1` you are printing the constructor parameter. In `Class2` you are printing the class member. To print the class member in `Class1` you must use `this`, because parameter names hide member names:

```
Class1(string name):name(move(name)) { cout << this->name << endl; }
```

Comment: Without std::move it works fine, however:
class Class3
  { 
public:
    string name;
    Class3(string name):name(name) { cout << name << endl; } // baz
   ~Class3() { cout << name << endl; }  // baz
  };

Comment: @Qaligula If you aren't moving the parameter, the parameter won't be empty. You are still printing the parameter, not the member.